# Issue with list data setting and order

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add the data into a list based on the key value of other list.Here auditMap has keys att_12,att_11 and oldValues has keys att_11,att_12 ,i want the order of oldValues to appear in the same way as auditMap so i am looping over.Here key should from auditMap and value from oldValues.I am not sure how to replace ?

```
List<FieldProperty> orderedList = new ArrayList<FieldProperty>();
            for (int i = 0; i < auditMap.size(); i++) {
                String auditKey = auditMap.get(i).getKey();
                for (int j = 0; j < oldValues.size(); j++) {
                    String oldAuditKey = oldValues.get(i).getKey();
                    String oldAuditValue = oldValues.get(i).getValue();
                    if (auditKey.equals(oldAuditKey)) {
                                                     orderedList.set(j, ???);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The orderedList will contain values in the order you added them. BTW It appears that auditMap is a List, not a Map. ?!

Comment: ya its a list ,both are list here

Comment: I would call it an `auditList` instead of a Map to avoid confusion.

Comment: ya i wil change it,but please tel me the solution for this

Comment: Use `orderList.add(fieldProperty);` to add elements, instead of set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) data structure here.

It retains the order of objects (as they were put into it). So you can iterate the map then and order will be the same.

Comment: i dont have map ,i am looping over a list.

Comment: Ok, you iterate over list (as source), but can use linkedhashmap (as target) - change data structure, if it better suites your task. If you still want to use lists try guava's filter method (your task can be reformulated, as i understood "Filter elements from auditMap which are present in oldValues": http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)